# A static variable trying to access another static variable

Tags: java

I was wondering, whether the following code are safe.

```
public class GUIBundle {

    // The technique known as the initialization on demand holder idiom, 
    // is as lazy as possible.
    // http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initialization_on_demand_holder_idiom
    //private static class BundleHolder {
    //    private static final ResourceBundle bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("org.yccheok.jstock.data.gui");
    //}
    private static final ResourceBundle bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("org.yccheok.jstock.data.gui");

    private GUIBundle() {
    }

    public static String getString(String key) {
        // return BundleHolder.bundle.getString(key);
        return bundle.getString(key);
    }
}
```

---

```
public class SellPortfolioChartJDialog extends javax.swing.JDialog {

    private static final String[] cNames = new String[] {
        GUIBundle.getString("BuyPortfolioTreeTableModel_NetGainValue")
    };
}
```

---

Since cNames is within static scope, is it safe for it to access static bundle? Does it make any different whether I am using lazy initialization technique?

I remember I came across an article (I lost the article anyway) talking about nondeterministic of initialization order of static variables. I am not sure whether the nondeterministic of initialization order of static variables, applied to the above case?

Comment: Your API returns `String` and you are trying to get `String[]` - this won't compile anyway. I think I understand the theme though, and I think this will work(safely) if you correct your code.

Comment: @ring he's building a String[] with 1 String in it.

Comment: the getString method should have "return bundle.getString(key)" and a ';' for cNames is missing, ...and it compiles, I guess a typo because of the commented code :)

Comment: @glowcoder, gotcha! the compilation issues made me ignore the curly braces around :) - that is what happens when someone posts incorrect example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the nondeterministic initialization order of static variables (in different compilation units) is a C/C++ "feature". In Java, static variables are initialized when their class is loaded, and within a single class in their order of declaration. So the order is deterministic (at least in a single threaded environment).

This guarantees that what you intend to do should work: when `GUIBundle` is first referenced, the classloader loads it and initializes `bundle` too. The call to `GUIBundle.getString()` happens only after the class initialization is done.

Comment: No, it is possible for initialization order to be indeterminate. Joshua Bloch has more information.

Comment: @DJClayworth, could you provide a more specific reference? I couldn't find any detail on this in Effective Java.

Comment: I cannot find either. Can you please provide reference?

Answer (score 1):

That works just fine. I got it to compile by keeping the principle the same but using different classes (I didn't want to bother getting your jars... :-).

Obviously there are some small problems, like how you declare your String[] needs to be

```
private static final String[] cNames = new String[] {
        GUIBundle.getString("BuyPortfolioTreeTableModel_NetGainValue")
    };
}
```

Other than that, it works just fine. The key to using statics in other statics is the order they're declared. You can't do this

```
static Foo b = a;
static Foo a = new Foo();
```

Answer (score 1):

I think its perfectly safe, You see because the when

```
GUIBundle.getString
```

is used in your JDialog subclass, the JVM will completely initialize (see java language spec loading, linking and initialization) the class GUIBundle before calling the method getString on it, which will initialize all the class (static) initializers in the class GUIBundle.

Edit: Read more about this in VM spec:
http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jvms/second_edition/html/Concepts.doc.html#16491

Answer (score 0):

To me it's safe.

`bundle` is initialized right after `GUIBuilder` is loaded and therfore before `getString` is called for the first time.